# mouseenter(or mouseover) with overlapping boxes

Tags: jquery, css

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".b").mousemove(function(event){            
            var relX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            var relY = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
            var relBoxCoords = "(" + relX + "," + relY + ")";
                    $('.b').addClass('active-b'); 
                    $('.aa, .c, .d').addClass('move-w-b'); 
                    $('.c').removeClass('active-c'); 
                    $('.aa, .b, .d').removeClass('move-w-c');
        });

        $(".c").mousemove(function(event){            
            var relX = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
            var relY = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
            var relBoxCoords = "(" + relX + "," + relY + ")";
                    $('.c').addClass('active-c'); 
                    $('.aa, .b, .d').addClass('move-w-c'); 
                    $('.b').removeClass('active-b'); 
                    $('.aa, .c, .d').removeClass('move-w-b');
        });

    });
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

.set {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.set-row {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 28vw;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.font {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2vw;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.aa {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    background: yellow;
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.b {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    background: red;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 1vw;
    left: 1vw;
}

.c {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    background: grey;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 2vw;
    left: 2vw;
}

.d {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 3vw;
    left: 3vw;
}

.b.active-b {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: .4s;
}

.aa.move-w-b {
    top: 3vw;
    left: 3vw;
    z-index: 9;
    transition: .4s;
}

.c.move-w-b {
    top: 1vw;
    left: 1vw;
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: .4s;
}

.d.move-w-b {
    top: 2vw;
    left: 2vw;
    transition: .4s;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="set">
    <div class="set-row">
            <div class="aa">
                <span class="font">a</span>
            </div>
            <div class="b">
                <span class="font">b</span>
            </div>
            <div class="c">
                <span class="font">c</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d">
                <span class="font">d</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

Div overlapping like several sheets of paper,
I try to make the 'Div' come to the front when I mouseover(mouseenter) each 'Div' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dddUJ.jpg)

But now, even if I put my mouse cursor on each 'div' area correctly,
there's confusion.
Not only 'div' but also the surrounding area of 'div' seems to be affected.

Comment: Please show us your code, without it's very hard to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with using `addClass` and `removeClass` you can achieve this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".a").mousemove(function(event){            
    $('.a').removeClass('bb cc dd');
    $('.a').addClass('aa'); 
    
    $('.b').removeClass('aa cc dd');
    $('.b').addClass('bb'); 
    
    $('.c').removeClass('aa bb dd');
    $('.c').addClass('cc'); 
                    
    $('.d').removeClass('aa bb cc');
    $('.d').addClass('dd'); 
  });
        
  $(".b").mousemove(function(event){            
    $('.a').removeClass('aa bb cc');
    $('.a').addClass('dd'); 
    
    $('.b').removeClass('bb cc dd');
    $('.b').addClass('aa'); 
    
    $('.c').removeClass('cc dd aa');
    $('.c').addClass('bb'); 
    
    $('.d').removeClass('dd aa bb');
    $('.d').addClass('cc'); 
  });

  $(".c").mousemove(function(event){         
    $('.a').removeClass('aa bb dd');
    $('.a').addClass('cc'); 
    
    $('.b').removeClass('aa bb cc');
    $('.b').addClass('dd'); 
    
    $('.c').removeClass('bb cc dd');
    $('.c').addClass('aa'); 
    
    $('.d').removeClass('aa cc dd');
    $('.d').addClass('bb'); 
  });
  
  $(".d").mousemove(function(event){         
    $('.a').removeClass('cc dd aa');
    $('.a').addClass('bb'); 
    
    $('.b').removeClass('dd aa bb');
    $('.b').addClass('cc'); 
    
    $('.c').removeClass('aa bb cc');
    $('.c').addClass('dd'); 
    
    $('.d').removeClass('bb cc dd');
    $('.d').addClass('aa'); 
  });
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    word-break: keep-all;
}

.set {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.set-row {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 28vw;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.font {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2vw;
    font-size: 5vw;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.a {
    background: yellow;
}

.b {
    background: red;
}

.c {
    background: grey;
}

.d {
    background: #fff;;
}

.a, .b, .c, .d {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 6px 2px #000;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 25vw;
}

.aa {
    z-index: 999999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: .4s;
}

.bb {
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 2vw;
    left: 2vw;
    transition: .4s;
}

.cc {
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 4vw;
    left: 4vw;
    transition: .4s;
}

.dd {
    z-index: 999;
    top: 6vw;
    left: 6vw;
    transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="set">
    <div class="set-row">
            <div class="a aa">
                <span class="font">a</span>
            </div>
            <div class="b bb">
                <span class="font">b</span>
            </div>
            <div class="c cc">
                <span class="font">c</span>
            </div>
            <div class="d dd">
                <span class="font">d</span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```